# fabricjs : shake objects on canvas on long press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs

i want to shake object on canvas on longpress, i want to know if there is any method to call it like shake(); or else.. 
or any way to implement it .

i tried using `$('#objectid').shake();` but it doesn't works any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you are not having any longpress event in fabric js canvas. you have to do some work around using html DOM events.

---

Second thing is that you are not having any excate shake animation in fabric js. Instead of that fabric have [animation type demo here](http://fabricjs.com/animation-easing/). Have a look at it and hope that it helps you.